# Woo checkout shipping method ajax validation

Tags: woocommerce

I am usign ajax checkout form and have removed all preselected shipping methods. That means that shipping radio buttons are not checked. I have also put the validation-required class to each radio input and when click complete button, the ajax response correctly returns an error "not shipping method selected....", but the class is not populated with extra "woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field" so to highlight.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work with preselected shipping methods in place?

Comment: It works. But with preselected radio there is no validation